# Why do I get error when attempt use IF in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I get the error `"IF" is not valid in this position.` as soon as I enter an `IF` in *WorkBench*. **Anyone who knows why?** Never get a chance to test this query.

```
USE arter;
IF (SELECT lokNavn FROM lokalitet WHERE lokNavn='Lodviken') IS NULL THEN 
 SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 2 END IF
```

Comment: You can only use `IF` statements in procedures, not ordinary queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IF` statements can only be used in procedures, not regular queries.

You can use the `IF()` function or a `CASE` expression.

```
SELECT IF(EXISTS(SELECT lokNavn FROM lokalitet WHERE lokNavn='Lodviken')), 1, 2)
```